# How to move directory into a directory with the same name?

Tags: directory, mv, macos

I have a directory `foo` with several files:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── a.txt
    └── b.txt
```

and I want to move it into a directory with the same name:

```
.
└── foo
    └── foo
        ├── a.txt
        └── b.txt
```

I'm currently creating a temporary directory `bar`, move `foo` into `bar` and rename `bar` to `foo` afterwards:

```
mkdir bar
mv foo bar
mv bar foo
```

But this feels a little cumbersome and I have to pick a name for `bar` that's not already taken.

Is there a more elegant or straight-forward way to achieve this? I'm on macOS if that matters.

Comment: How do you feel about links?  That is, do other non-sym-links exist linking to original `foo`?  Do those links now need to point to `foo/foo`?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica indeed, there are some GUI applications having a link to `foo` (e.g. "recently opened files"). To keep those working, `foo` itself has to be moved, rather than just its content. (otherwise those links would refer to the new parent directory which isn't desired)

Comment: But are you sure these are plain links and not symlinks?  Plain links increment the link count, symlinks do not. Plain links mean if the file is deleted, the file still lives in the other directory.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica those are not links in the file system. The applications store the file's unique ID which is based on its inode number.

Comment: `mkdir foo/foo; mv foo/* foo/foo` prints an error but still results in your expected outcome (at least on Ubuntu). Now: if you are interested on how inodes "move" then the result is not what you want (the original `foo` directory is not the inner `foo` so if you access via inode or something you will not find the expected structure).

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I'm aware of that. My intention is to move `foo` (the whole directory, not just its content) into a new directory. That new directory should be named "foo" as well. My example above (`mkdir bar && mv foo bar && mv bar foo`) already works as expected in that regard.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To safely create a temporary directory in the current directory, with a name that is not already taken, you can use `mktemp -d` like so:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d "$PWD"/tmp.XXXXXXXX)   # using ./tmp.XXXXXXXX would work too
```

The `mktemp -d` command will create a directory at the given path, with the `X`-es at the end of the pathname replaced by random alphanumeric characters. It will return the pathname of the directory that was created, and we store this value in `tmpdir`.<sup>1</sup>

This `tmpdir` variable could then be used when following the same procedure that you are already doing, with `bar` replaced by `"$tmpdir"`:

```
mv foo "$tmpdir"
mv "$tmpdir" foo
unset tmpdir
```

The `unset tmpdir` at the end just removes the variable.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Usually, one *should* be able to set the `TMPDIR` environment variable to a directory path where one wants to create temporary files or directories with `mktemp`, but the utility on macOS seems to work subtly differently with regards to this than the same utility on other BSD systems, and will create the directory in a totally different location.  The above would however work on macOS. Using the slightly more convenient `tmpdir=$(TMPDIR=$PWD mktemp -d)` or even `tmpdir=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp -d)` would only be an *issue* on macOS if the default temporary directory was on another partition and the `foo` directory contained a lot of data (i.e. it would be slow).</sub>

Comment: Aside from the double copy, a different partition might also have insufficient space for the temporary file storage.

Comment: @roaima Yes, but hopefully it was clear enough that the command that I actually show will create a unique name in the _current_ directory.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I was playing with `mktemp` put couldn't find a way to create a temporary directory in the current working directory. Even though my TMPDIR is on the same partition, I don't want to move the files outside the current directory in case something goes wrong. Prefixing it with `$PWD` did the trick!

Comment: @Stefan Yes, this is an issue. See my question on the topic: [mktemp on macOS not honouring $TMPDIR](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/555058)

Answer (score 10):

On macOS, you can install the `rename` command (a Perl script) using Homebrew:

```
brew install rename
```

Then using the `-p` (a la `mkdir`) to have it make any necessary directories, and `-A` to add a prefix:

```
% mkdir -p foo/bar; touch foo/{a,b}.txt foo/bar/c.txt
% rename -p -A foo/ foo/*
% tree foo
foo
└── foo
    ├── a.txt
    ├── b.txt
    └── bar
        └── c.txt
```

Run with `-n` to show changes without renaming (dry-run):

```
% rename -p -A foo/ foo/* -n
'foo/a.txt' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/a.txt'
'foo/b.txt' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/b.txt'
'foo/bar' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/bar'
```

If you have dot files, so that a simple `*` won't pick them up, then use other methods with `rename`:

- With bash, (mis)use `GLOBIGNORE` to get `*` to match dot files:

  ```
  $ GLOBIGNORE=.; rename -p -A foo/ foo/* -n
  'foo/.baz' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/.baz'
  'foo/a.txt' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/a.txt'
  'foo/b.txt' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/b.txt'
  'foo/bar' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/bar'
  ```
- Or use `find` with `-print0` and `rename` with `-0`:

  ```
  % find foo -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | rename -0 -p -A foo/ -n
  Reading filenames from STDIN
  Splitting on NUL bytes
  'foo/b.txt' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/b.txt'
  'foo/a.txt' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/a.txt'
  'foo/bar' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/bar'
  'foo/.baz' would be renamed to 'foo/foo/.baz'
  ```

Comment: What does the `-p` do on macOS? I don't have a `-p` option for my `rename`. Same for the `-A`, actually. What do they do?

Comment: @terdon `-p` is like with `mkdir` - it creates missing directories. `-a` adds a suffix, `-A` adds a prefix. I assume your rename is one of the Perl renames on a Linux?

Comment: Yes, it's `perl-rename` but has neither a `-p` nor a `-A` option. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I didn't edit anything here. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Does your perl-rename report a version number?

Comment: Duh, so you didn't! My bad, I had missed that you had already explained these somehow, sorry! I have `perl-rename 1.9`. I suspect macOS just brings in one of the other ones: [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230)

Answer (score 10):

As long as the contents are not sufficient to exceed the maximum parameter limits, (and you don't mind an "acceptable" error message) then it doesn't need to be any more complicated than this:

```
mkdir foo/foo
mv foo/* foo/foo
```

Amendment to handle hidden files:

```
mkdir foo/foo
mv foo/{.,}* foo/foo
```

Comment: Yes it has to be to handle hidden files: `mv foo/* foo/.* foo/foo`

Comment: `mv foo/* foo` does what? It appears to be moving stuff to where they were originally located.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Better then to enable `dotglob` and `nullglob` (in `bash`) than trying to glob files that might not exist.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo missing the subdir off the target. Also added in handling for dot files as well. I concede it’s hacky, but the globs all exist — we just created subdirectory `foo`, and `..` would match for dot files I think.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest the other way around. Don't move the directory, but only its content:

```
.
└── foo
    ├── a.txt
    └── b.txt
```

```
mkdir foo/foo
```

```
.
└── foo
    ├── foo
    ├── a.txt
    └── b.txt
```

```
cd foo
mv $(ls | grep -v '^foo$') foo
cd -
```

```
.
└── foo
    └── foo
        ├── a.txt
        └── b.txt
```

If you have bash, you can also do

```
shopt -s extglob
cd foo
mv !(foo) foo
cd -
```

(as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986635/how-to-exclude-a-folder-when-using-the-mv-command)) to avoid running ls and grep.

The advantage of this solution is that it's really simple.

Disadvantages (as pointed out in the comments):

- Cannot handle hidden files (`ls -A` fixes it, but not `ls -a`)
- Cannot handle filenames containing spaces (can be fixed by quotes: `mv "$(ls | grep -v '^foo$')" foo`
- Cannot handle filenames containing newlines and other special characters

Most disadvantages can be addressed by using some bash trick, but if one must handle crazy filenames, it's better to use more robust approach, as described in other answers.

Comment: You would need `ls -A` there (or `ls -a` and `grep -v`, if your `ls` does not hove `-A`) in order to move all the filenames starting with `.` . Then again, if you *do* have GNU coreutils, then `mv` will happily correctly handle trying to move directory into itself (with just a warning) when you try `mv foo/* foo/foo`

Comment: @MatijaNalis on my system (Arch Linux, coreutils 8.31-3) `mv` returns 1 to shell when moving the directory into itself.

Comment: Rather than your `grep / mv` -combination, I'd suggest using `find`. e.g.:  `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'foo' -print0 | xargs -0 -I mv '{}' foo`. You might otherwise risk errors on filenames with e.g. spaces.

Comment: This will miss any hidden files, as already pointed out, and will also fail on any file names with whitespace. [Parsing `ls` is never a good idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: `mv foo/* foo/.* foo/foo` works like a charm. It does print an error but still produces the expected result. It should handle spaces, newlines  etc and hidden files too.

Comment: In addition to @terdons correct objection, it will also fail to move files that have the substring "foo", such as "buffoon" for a draft biography of the UK prime minister.

Comment: @gerrit only the variant with `!(foo)`. The grep variant has this handled.

Comment: For large directories this creates more metadata churn, removing each dirent from one directory and adding it to another.

Comment: Yes, `mv * foo/` will print an error message, but it will *also* move the other args.  I just tried it on my own Arch Linux system.  That's exactly what @MatijaNalis said: correctly handle it with just a warning.

Answer (score 6):

You've pretty much nailed it already. You could pick a different name for the transient directory, such as the target name with the current date/time in nanoseconds and our PID as a composite suffix, but this still presupposes the directory doesn't already exist:

```
dir=foo                         # The directory we want to nest
now=$(date +'%s_%N')            # Seconds and nanoseconds
mkdir "$dir.$now.$$"            # Create a transient directory
mv -f "$dir" "$dir.$now.$$/"    # Move our directory inside transient directory
mv -f "$dir.$now.$$" "$dir"     # Rename the transient directory to the name with which we started
```

If you want a guaranteed robust solution, I would loop around the `mkdir` until it was successful

```
now=$(date +'%s_%N')
while ! mkdir -m700 "$dir.$now.$$" 2>/dev/null
do
    sleep 0.$$
    now=$(date +'%s_%N')
done
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to create an "unnamed" directory then move my directory into it and assign a name afterwards. Like a nameless inode, but I guess that doesn't exists.

Comment: @Stefan if you had a directory that was unnamed how would you reference it in the filesystem?

Comment: Via it's inode number, e.g. `find . -inum 123456 -exec mv {} foo \;` would rename the file with inode number `123456` to `foo`.

Comment: @Stefan there's no way to access a file directly by its inode number; if that were possible, it would break completely break the security model. If creating another temporary dir in the parent dir of `foo` is complicated, you can restructure the `foo` dir in place: `mkdir foo/foo; mv foo/* foo/foo` (for the last part, you can ignore the error, or use extended globbing to skip the `foo/foo` subdir itself).

Comment: @mosvy remember dot files too

Comment: @Stefan your `find` references (uses) a directory by its name, where its identifying criterion is the inode number.

Comment: there's `dotglob`, `extglob` and all the bash zoo; I've assumed that the OP's Q was more of the general kind (eg. in C, perl, etc. you could use readdir directly, which would be faster than globbing as it would not imply sorting).

Comment: @mosvy if I'm not mistaken that would result in another / new inode number for the nested `foo`. I really want to move the directory itself, not its content.

Comment: @roaima maybe my `find` example doesn't work. It was just to illustrate what I had in mind, i.e. create some anonymous directory, perform the operations and – when finished – name it.

Comment: @Stefan why? what importance has the inode number of the directory?

Comment: @mosvy the directories are shown in the "recently opened" list of some GUI applications. It's not a critical requirement but preserving the inode numbers would be more convenient.

Answer (score 6):

```
mkdir foo/foo && mv foo/!(foo) foo/foo
```

You need to cd into the directory where the source folder (foo) is.

Then run the command above. It will create a folder called of the same name and move the contents of the parent foo into the child foo directory (except the child directory, hence the ! designation).

If the child foo directory already exists you can ignore the first part and just run the mv command:

```
mv foo/!(foo) foo/foo
```

In MacOS you may need to set the extglob option:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: Explanation: In Bash, `!(foo)` is like `*` except it won't match `foo`.  It's a glob expression.  Does it match dotfiles, though?  Getting that right is one downside to the move-all-the-files approach.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggestions above, you might want to checkout rsync. Before I even start, always remember to use the `--dry-run` option with rsync before running it without it. The `--dry-run` will tell you what would happen in real life.

rsync has many options that can not only help copy/move files, but also speed up the process. Here is one way to get your job done. The `--remove-source-files`option deletes files from the source after the move process (which is actually a copy followed by a delete). Notice that the rsync command first reads the contents of foo, creates the directory foo within the existing directory called foo, then starts the copy process. It ends with deleting the source files in foo. Caution: Pay particular attention to the slashes for the directory names.

There are other considerations as many have pointed above (like symlinks), but a `man rsync` will help you pick the options that you need. A note here: Since you have asked for a solution for files, this will work. This will not remove empty directories that will be left behind. I am not aware of a way to do so without an additional step, so if anyone can add to this, thanks in advance!

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
touch aaa bbb ccc ddd
cd ..
rsync -av --remove-source-files foo foo/
```

a = archive mode

v = verbose

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't touch foo and you don't have issues with identical names. Instead, create a directory with the same name inside it and move everything there. Use the $_ trick for that and && to make it a one-liner:

```
cd foo && mkdir $_ && mv * $_
```

This will throw a harmless error (*mv: rename foo to foo/foo: Invalid argument*) that you can ignore.

Advantage over other answers: You only need to type the directory name once, so you can't make mistakes with typos.

---

you can mix this with other answers for even better effect:

- `mv {.,}* $_` will take care of hidden files (at the cost of more errors that you can also ignore)
- `mv ./!(foo)` will avoid the error message, but only if you set `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: IMHO, in would be better to use the `dotglob` shell option and use that with the `extglob` variation (if there is a destination directory, you left it out).

Comment: Another disadvantage is that it doesn't preserve `foo`'s permissions or extended attributes (e.g. folder color or custom icon in macOS). Those would stick to the outer `foo`.

Comment: @Stefan that's true, but it wasn't requested in the question.

Comment: Well, in the question I said that I want to move a directory `foo` into a directory with the same name. That implies that the original directory becomes the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually deceptively simple and I'm shocked nobody else has offered this answer yet, so here I go
Using the following for example...

```
$ mkdir foo
$ mkdir bar
$ mkdir ./bar/foo
$ touch ./bar/foo/file1 && touch ./bar/foo/file2 && touch ./bar/foo/file3
$ ls ./
bar/ foo/
$ ls ./bar/foo
file1 file2 file3
```

Now comes the magic part

```
$ mv ./bar/foo ./foo/
$ ls ./foo/
foo/
$ ls ./foo/foo/
file1 file2 file3
```

Now why does this work? 
I can't give you the most precise answer as I'm just a neophyte - but I understand it comes down to how trailing `/` characters are treated on folders.

Look closely at that mv command

`$ mv ./bar/foo ./foo/`

Notice how the target folder of files is specified without a trailing `/`, while the destination sharing the target folder's name has been specified using a trailing `/`'. This is your magic ticket, and can bite you in the ass if you aren't paying attention.

I'm sorry I can't offer a more elaborate answer than that at present, but perhaps someone more fluently knowledgeable will take the liberty of editing my answer.

In any event, this would seem to be the most simple and straightforward solution, with a single use of the `ls` command and no creation of intermediary folders.

Hope it works for you, cheers!

Comment: Disclaimer: I personally do not have access to an OSX system to cross check this on. I'm making a wild assumption that the shell environment on Mac behaves within this context the same as I've encountered in bash and zsh. If it doesn't work the same for you, the difference in shell environments may be why. Perhaps someone else with the right hardware can test this and comment about how it went for them.