# mktemp on macOS not honouring $TMPDIR

Tags: environment-variables, macos, mktemp

I've noticed this before, but it was brought up again as I was answering "[How to move directory into a directory with the same name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555047)":

The `mktemp` utility on macOS does not behave the same as the utility of the same name on Linux or BSD (or least OpenBSD) with respect to the `TMPDIR` environment variable.

To create a temporary file in the *current* directory, I can usually say

```sh
tmdfile=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp)
```

or

```sh
tmpfile=$(TMPDIR=$PWD mktemp)
```

(and similarly for a temporary directory with `mktemp -d`).

On macOS, I will have to force the utility to use the current directory by giving it an actual template, as in

```sh
tmpfile=(mktemp ./tmp.XXXXXXXX)
```

because using the more convenient `tmpfile=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp)` would ignore the `TMPDIR` variable and create the file under `/var/folders/qg/s5jp5ffx2p1fxv0hy2l_p3hm0000gn/T` or in a similarly named directory.

The manual for `mktemp` on macOS mentions that

> If the `-t prefix` option is given, `mktemp` will generate a template string based on the prefix and
>   the `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` configuration variable if available.  Fallback locations if
>   `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` is not available are `TMPDIR` and `/tmp`.

On my system, `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` appears to be unset:

```
$ getconf _CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR
getconf: no such configuration parameter `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR'
```

but e.g.

```sh
tmpfile=$(TMPDIR=. mktemp -t hello)
```

still creates a file under `/var/folders/.../` (also when using `$PWD` in place of `.`).

I'm noticing that

```
$ getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR
/var/folders/qg/s5jp5ffx2p1fxv0hy2l_p3hm0000gn/T/
```

but this doesn't help me much as I wouldn't know how to change this value.

The macOS `mktemp` utility is said to come from FreeBSD, which in turn got it from OpenBSD (which must have been quite a while ago).

Question:

Is this a bug (or omission) in the macOS implementation of `mktemp`? How do I change the `DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` value (or `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` mentioned by the manual) from within a script (I would ideally want to unset it so that `$TMPDIR` takes precedence)?

Comment: mktemp is a non-standard command; there's no requirement that it use `TMPDIR` in preference to any other place, and the `mktemp` from MacOS was changed to use [`confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR)`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-198/mktemp/mktemp.c.auto.html). Based on what I've skimmed from this guys [analysis](http://www.magnusviri.com/Mac/what-is-var-folders.html), I don't think you can change the path returned by that. Keep using `mktemp` with a template.

Comment: @mosvy I'm aware. The wording of the bit of the manual that I quoted does lead me to wonder if the `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` variable could be unset or changed somehow, or whether there are situations where it would be unset. Why would there be a fallback to `$TMPDIR` otherwise? Also, since it's inherited from OpenBSD via FreeBSD, I was expecting it to behave similarly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> `/var/folders/qg/s5jp5ffx2p1fxv0hy2l_p3hm0000gn/`

This is your Darwin *user local* directory.  Its name is simply a modified base 32 encoding of the concatenation your MacOS *User UUID* and your MacOS (BSD) user ID.  The first two letters of the encoding are used as a "bucket" system to attempt to keep directory sizes low.  Those two characters are the encoded first 10 bits of the User UUID, because in base 32 one digit is of course 5 bits.

Its subdirectories are your *user local temp* and *user local cache* directories.  Their names used to be `-Caches-` and `-Tmp-` but those have been shortened to `C` and `T`.  It should be apparent that all of these names are fixed and unchangeable, unless you are willing to change your user ID or user UUID.

When an application calls `confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR,…)`, the C library first tries to ensure that you have a *user local* directory, then tries to ensure that you have a *user local temp* directory within it.

Ensuring that you have a *user local* directory is non-trivial, because you do not have write access to `/var/folders`.  So there is a `dirhelper` Mach launch dæmon that runs with superuser privileges and that securely creates these directories, responding to Mach IPC calls from applications from within the implementation of `confstr()` in their C libraries.  You *do* have write access to the *user local* directory (once created) and so the C libraries just `mkdir()` its children directly if they do not already exist.

If this succeeeds, the `mktemp` program never looks at the value of the `TMPDIR` environment variable, because the fallback in `mktemp`'s code is from calling `confstr()` to calling `getenv()` not the other way around.  `confstr(_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR,…)` will almost always succeed.  Its failure modes are things like the `dirhelper` launch dæmon not being able to be run, or the attempt to create the `T` subdirectory failing with an error *other than* that the directory already exists.

You could put something other than a directory as `T`, but this will be regularly cleaned up by the `dirhelper` launch dæmon, which is also what deletes stuff in `/var/folders`.  Disabling the `dirhelper` launch dæmon will cause problems of its own, not the least of which will be `/var/folders` not getting cleaned.  Denying yourself write permission on your *user local* directory will potentially interfere with all *other* uses of it, it being used for more than just a `T` subdirectory.

Your best option (aside from supplying a template) is to make `T` a symbolic link, but this is still far from good because it will of course affect all running applications of yours that might, at the very same instant, be wanting to create a temporary file.

Neither `DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` nor `_CS_DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` are variable names.  They are names, for the `getconf` utility and for the `confstr()` library function, of a configuration string.

Comment: Thanks for this. It appears that I will have to test explicitly for macOS in the future, or just go over to always use an explicit template. Much thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to add that this is a really good answer and echo @Kusalananda's thanks, but I mostly wanted to gripe that this is a **godamn ridiculous implementation of mktemp.. ** Seriously, it depends on a daemon that ensures that a user directory not only exists in /var/folders, but has the proper writes. So, so angry..