# Avoid symlink race rcondition with "mv" in Bash

Tags: bash, security, symlink, mv

I want to safely write to a destination file (as root, unter common Linux'es) with "echo" (or catany other Bash built-in stuff) like this

```
echo "foo" > /destination/dir/filename
```

But the problem is that /destination/dir could be accessible for normal system users, so there is the risk of symlink conditions.

I read all the "how to" for preventing TOC-TOU stuff when using C, so NOT checking for symlink/remove it and open then (the common recommendations seems to be to open() with O_NOFOLLOW).

But all of this (access to kernel open() and it's flags) is not possible via Bash (or am I wrong?).

Then I got the idea of

- creating a tempfile with mktemp
- chown+chmod the tempfile appropriately
- write the contents to write to the tempfile
- move the tempfile to the destination dir with the Bash param "-T"

So as some Bash peudo-code (without error checking at some places)

```
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)

chown root:root $TEMPFILE
chmod 0600 $TEMPFILE
echo "contents" > $TEMPFILE
mv -T $TEMPFILE /destination/dir/filename
```

I just tested it with "/destination/dir/filename" to be a symlink to a system file, but it worked: "mv" did move the tempfile correctly to the "filename", the symlink was removed (which is was I intended), no file was overwritten.

Is there anythink I missed out with regards to security/race conditions etc.?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Check if `/destination/dir/filename` exists, remove it and then `echo "foo" > /destination/dir/filename`?

Comment: @Cyrus you still have a race condition there - it's just that now it's between the "_remove it_" and the _`echo "foo"`_

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that `/destination/dir` exists safely. (If it does not, then create the topmost directory with sufficiently restricted permissions that its subdirectories cannot be accessed or created by a non-root user. Then relax the permissions once the hierarchy is complete.)

One approach is to create the file with a temporary but unique name using `mktemp` inside the target directory. Then write its contents, and finally `mv` it to the destination.

The key point is that when using `mv` with a source and destination on the same filesystem the destination will be removed as part of the rename process: it's an atomic operation performed through the `rename(2)` system call by the kernel itself:

> If `newpath` already exists, it will be atomically replaced, so that there is no point at which another process  attempting to access `newpath` will find it missing. However, there will probably be a window in which both `oldpath` and `newpath` refer to the file being renamed.

A simple implementation, very similar to your own, might be this:

```
base='/destination/dir'                # Use '.' for current directory
file='filename'

tf=$(mktemp "$base/XXXXXXXXXX.tmp")    # Created with mode 600
echo "contents" >"$tf"                 # Always double-quote variables when used
if ! mv -Tf "$tf" "$base/$file"
then
    echo "Error writing to $base/$file" >&2
    rm -f "$tf"                        # Clean up temporary file
fi
```

In a POSIX world, implementing an equivalent to `mv -T` is harder, and here I've relied on being able to create a temporary directory. In a real situation this would probably be best handled in a loop that repeats `mkdir` with different directory names until it succeeds, but here I only attempt the creation once:

```
base='/destination/dir'                # Use '.' for current directory
file='filename'

td="$base/dir.$$.tmp"                  # Must be unique
if mkdir -m700 "$td"                   # Will fail if not unique
then
    echo "contents" >"$td/$file"
    if ! mv -f "$td/$file" "$base/"    # Overwrite/replace $base/filename, or fail
    then
        echo "Error writing to $base/$file" >&2
    fi
    rm -rf "$td"                       # Clean up temporary directory
else
    echo "Error creating temporary directory $td" >&2
fi
```

The `mktemp` command is also not POSIX, but there are [suggested implementations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/614808/100397) available for that.