# How to apply a patch as part of a pipe? In other words, how to patch stdin?

Tags: shell-script, pipe, diff, patch

I want to apply a unified diff from `mypatch.diff` to stdin and output the result to stdout.

So far, I have tried:

```
patch -i mypatch.diff -o - -u originalfile
```

Which successfully applies `mypatch.diff` and prints the result to stdout. However, I still have to provide the original file as `originalfile`, not via stdin.

And if I try something like:

```
patch -i mypatch.diff -o - -u -
```

Then the patch gets rejected:

```
patching file -
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file -.rej
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like GNU `patch` has an option for that. `-` means stdin for `-i` or stdout for `-o` (and for `-r` is interpreted as discarding rejects) but for the file to patch `-` is interpreted as the file called `-` in the current directory.

Also, `patch` will want to create files with `.orig` or `.rej` suffix when relevant based on the name of the file to patch.

It looks like `patch` won't let you patch symlinks, so on Linux, using /dev/stdin or /proc/self/fd/0 won't work.

If using `zsh`, you can use the `=(...)` form of process substitution that uses a temporary file:

```
patch -i mypatch.diff -r - -o - =(cat)
```

Note that for `-o -` and `-r -`, you need GNU `patch` 2.6 or newer (see [commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git/commit/?id=2e583114c723b678977579dd7156049867832c29) and [commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git/commit/?id=b80bfda68fe5f01f5163fa4877f45dd4334c6abb)).

Comment: @finefoot, not much point con`cat`enating a single file. Use `<input patch...` instead of `cat input | patch`. You'd also want to add some error handling, possibly signal handling to handle clean-up (I don't think zsh does signal handling though for the temp file it creates with `=(...)`).

Comment: @finefoot. Also use `cat > "$tmpfile"` rather than `tee "$tmpfile" >/dev/null`. No point in duplicating it and discarding one of the copies. In zsh, you could use just `>$tmpfile` but that would still run `cat` under the hood, you still something to do the reading and the writing there.

Comment: Hahaha, you're too fast for me. :) I wanted to post everything first and then reply in the comments. Re: "not much point concatenating a single file" Yes, that was only an example to show the pipe. Re: "use cat (...) rather than tee" Very good point. I don't know what I was thinking there.

Comment: I also realized that `mktemp` isn't POSIX and my Debian doesn't have `m4` installed by default, so I wanted to have a more general POSIX solution. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/738570 I posted it here if you're in the mood for more proofreading. :) Let me check out your edit on my post now. Thank you so much for your participation on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work-around solution for POSIX shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
patchstdin() (
    set -o errexit
    tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
    trap 'rm -rf -- "$tmpdir"' EXIT
    trap 'exit 1' HUP INT TERM
    cat >"$tmpdir/original"
    patch "$@" -o "$tmpdir/patched" "$tmpdir/original"
    cat "$tmpdir/patched"
)
```

Assuming `yourcommand` produces the output that is supposed to get patched, and `anothercommand` is expecting to receive the patched output, you would call:

```
yourcommand | patchstdin -i patch.diff | anothercommand
```

Note that `mktemp` is not part of POSIX. See [Why is there no mktemp command in POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614808/why-is-there-no-mktemp-command-in-posix) for more information and [How create a temporary file in shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181937/how-create-a-temporary-file-in-shell-script) for solutions for POSIX shell.

Comment: Note that `-o -` is not POSIX either, or at least AFAICT POSIX would require the output to go to a file called `-` in the current working directory.

Comment: Personally, I avoid `set -e` for anything but the simplest scripts, so typically not when functions of subscripts are used. I tend to prefer the `set -o errexit` syntax.

Comment: you may want to use `mktemp -d` and use two separate tempfiles for input and output. You'd then delete the whole directory with both files and potential rej/orig files (I find that GNU `patch` saves rejects to `-.rej` with `-o -`)

Comment: Thanks. :) I took your advice and changed it to a temp folder with two files. I also took your advice and used the more explicit `set -o errexit` instead of `set -e`. Again, thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: Or did you mean to say that you prefer `|| exit` over `set -o errexit` here?  If yes, just a personal preference or is there an argument for this choice? I feel like as I use the shell more and more, my scripts get a little more extensive and I add error handling and it helps to just `set -o errexit` once at the beginning.

Comment: errexit is completely unreliable and unportable and can't replace proper error handling. At best it's only marginally better than not doing any error handling at all. See for instance https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105. Here that `errexit` would be cancelled in `pathstdin ... && echo Patch applied successfully` for instance. My rule is *subshells or functions => no errexit*

Comment: I think your patch command may be back to front? The docs say it should be `patch [options] [originalfile [patchfile]]` but it looks like you have the patch first.